# DNN Client Side Variables

Tags: javascript, dotnetnuke, skinning

In DNN, how can I get portal settings like page id, portal language, etc as a variable for javascript? I have tried something like this:

```
<% DotNetNuke.UI.Utilities.ClientAPI.RegisterClientVariable(Me.Page, "pageTitle", PortalSettings.ActiveTab.TabName, True) %>
```

and

```
var pageTitle = dnn.getVar('pageTitle');
```

but no luck, it just shows that variable "PageTitle" is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example from: https://github.com/ChrisHammond/dnnCHAT/blob/master/View.ascx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var moduleId:<%= ModuleId %>;
   var tabId:<%= TabId %>;
</script>
```

Where ModuleId is the parameter you want to set. If you're doing something with portalsettings you could do PortalSettings.PortalName, or any other valid value.